# Pulling correct results from my PitchValues Table

Tags: t-sql

I am getting a tad frustrated and was wondering if you can help:

I have a Pitch Values Table with the following Columns PitchValues_Skey, PitchType_Skey (this is a foreign key), Start Date, End Date and finally value:

For Example:

```
1    7   01/01/2010    31/12/2010   £15
2    7   01/01/2011    31/12/2011   £20
```

And all I want to do is update my Bookings table with how much each booking is going to be, so I put together the code below which worked fine when I only had 2010 data, but I know have 2011 and 2012 and want to update it but it will only update with the 2010 prices.

```
SELECT        Bookings.Booking_Skey, DATEDIFF(day, Bookings.ArrivalDate, Bookings.DepartureDate) * PitchValues.Value AS BookingValue, 
                         PitchValues.PitchType_Skey
FROM            Bookings INNER JOIN
                         PitchValues ON Bookings.PitchType_Skey = PitchValues.PitchType_Skey
WHERE        (Bookings.Booking_Skey = 1)
```

So when I run the query above I would expect to see one line of data but instead I see 4 (See Below)

I would expect this:

```
Booking_Skey    BookingValue    PitchType_Skey
      1               420                     4
```

But I get this

```
Booking_Skey    BookingValue    PitchType_Skey
     1                 420                  4
     1                 453.6                4
     1                 476.7                4
     1                 476.7                4
```

Comment: If you are only checking Bookings.Booking_Skey = 1, then all of the given tuples are a match. So the output is correct!

Comment: But bookings_Skey should only have 1 line of data because the arrival date for this booking is in 2010 and not in 2011, 2012 etc

Comment: but where are you checking for the date? Or are you saying that the table itself should have only that value?

Comment: That's my problem I don't know. My PitchValue table has a start and and an end date of when a certain value is valid for example PitchType 1 = £9 but only between 01/01/2010 and 31/12/2010 but between 01/01/2011 and 31/12/2011 the value of the same pitch type is £10.20, Each year has different prices.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now, thanks for your help.

```
SELECT  Bookings.Booking_Skey, DATEDIFF(DAY, Bookings.ArrivalDate, Bookings.DepartureDate) * PitchValues.Value AS BookingValue, PitchValues.PitchType_Skey
FROM    Bookings
INNER JOIN PitchValues ON Bookings.PitchType_Skey = PitchValues.PitchType_Skey
    AND Bookings.ArrivalDate BETWEEN PitchValues.StartDate AND PitchValues.EndDate
WHERE (Bookings.Booking_Skey = 1)
```